# Can a Slack app assess user activity and give targeted notifications?

Tags: slack, slack-api

We would like to build a slack app that analyses the activity of a user, sees who they interact with most and then send them a notification when it is the birthday of someone they interact with a lot.

Is that first step possible? Could the app have access to the user activity in order to see who they interact with the most through slack?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What you ask for is **not possible using normal APIs**.

Also, what you are asking is monitoring users and their interactions, which will raise a lot of **privacy concerns**.